# powershell: Set-Location / cd inside a function fails

Tags: powershell, alias

I just tried to set up an alias to go into my profile ie I want a short cut to cd'ing to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs`.

Whilst I can submit this command interactively and it works ok, I tried to put this inside a function but it failed ...

```
function cdht { cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs" }
```

fails with following error:

```
cdht : The term 'cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs"' is not 
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ cdht
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: 
    (cd "C:\Program ...Apache2\htdocs":String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I also tried with single quotes, same error.

Actually, I stared off trying to set an alias:

```
Set-Alias cdht 'cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs"'
```

but this fails with the exact same error message.

Stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an alias and a function have the same name (in your case `cdht`), the alias takes precedence over the function. So when you call `cdht` you are calling the invalid alias.

Try `Remove-Item Alias:\cdht` then enter `cdht` to call the function.

Comment: Thanks Rynant. I just started a new PS session and it worked fine, cheers